# Proving the following set of real numbers is a field

Tags: field-theory

Show that the following set $A$ of real numbers under addition and multipication is a field:

$A = {a + b\sqrt{2} : a,b \ \text{rational}}$

I am not sure if I am right but here is what I have thus far:

Closure: Let $a_{1} + b_{1}\sqrt{2}$, $a_{2} + b_{2}\sqrt{2}\in \mathbb{R}$. Then $(a_{1} + b_{1}\sqrt{2})+ (a_{2} + b_{2}\sqrt{2}) = (a_{1} + a_{2}) + (b_{1} + b_{2})\sqrt{2}\in A$.

Now, $(a_{1} + b_{1}\sqrt{2})\times (a_{2} + b_{2}\sqrt{2}) = (a_{1}\times a_{2} + 2\times b_{1}\times b_{2}) + (a_{1}\times b_{2} + b_{1}\times a_{2})\sqrt{2}\in A$
So both addition and multipication are closed on $A$

Associativity: As addition and multipication are associative on $\mathbb{R}$ it follows from Restriction of Operation Associativity that they are also associative on the set $A$.

Commutativity: As addition and multipication are commutative on $\mathbb{R}$ it follows from Restriction of Operation Commutativity that they are also commutative on the set $A$.

Identity: We have $(a + b\sqrt{2}) + (0 + 0\sqrt{2}) = (a + 0) + (b + 0)\sqrt{2} = a + b\sqrt{2}$ and similarly for $(0 + 0\sqrt{2}) + (a + b\sqrt{2})$. So, $(0 + 0\sqrt{2})$ is the identity for addition on $A$. Now, for multipication we have $(a + b\sqrt{2})(1 + 0\sqrt{2}) = (a\times 1 + 2\times b\times 0) + (b\times 1 + a\times 0)\sqrt{2} = a + b\sqrt{2}$ and similarly for $(1 + 0\sqrt{2})(a + b\sqrt{2})$. So, $(1 + 0\sqrt{2})$ is the identity for multipication on $A$.

Inverses: $(a + b\sqrt{2}) + (-a + (-b)\sqrt{2}) = (a - a) + (b - b)\sqrt{2} = 0 + 0\sqrt{2}$ and similarly for $(-a + (-b)\sqrt{2}) + (a + b\sqrt{2})$. So, $(-a + (-b)\sqrt{2})$ is the inverse of $(a + b\sqrt{2})$ for addition on $A$.\
For product inverse consider the difference of squares: $(a + b\sqrt{2})(a - b\sqrt{2}) = a^{2} - 2b^{2}$ which leads to $(a + \sqrt{2})(\frac{a - b\sqrt{2}}{a^{2} - 2b^{2}}) = 1 = 1 + 0\sqrt{2}$. So, demonstrating that the product inverse of $(a + b\sqrt{2})$ is $\frac{a}{a^{2} - 2b^{2}} - \frac{b\sqrt{2}}{a^{2} - 2b^{2}}$ as $a,b$ are rational, it follows that so are $\frac{a}{a^{2} - 2b^{2}}$ and $\frac{b}{a^{2} - 2b^{2}}$. So, the product inverse $(a + b\sqrt{2})\in A$

Distributivity: We have the Real Multipication Distributes over addition, so by Restriction of Operation Distrbutibity, multipication is distributive over addition on $A$.

Comment: Indeed you are wrong. In order to show commutativity and associativity in any set $A$ you need to show that for any $x,y,z\in A$ $$x+y=y+x,$$ and $$(x+y)+z=x+(y+z).$$ Moreover, here you don't need to show these axioms since you are in a subset of the reals.

Comment: Most of the properties are not ones you need to show here as they are inherited from the reals themselves. What you need to show is that the set is closed under sums, products, additive inverses and multiplicative inverses.

Comment: Note that you also need to prove that $\,a^2-2b^2\ne 0\,$ else you divide by $0$ when inverting by rationalizing the denominator.

Comment: @BillDubuque I need to prove that $a^{2} - 2b^{2} \neq 0 $ under the inverse section?

Comment: @morgan Yes, else you divide by $0.\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque do you think it would be ok to just include the proof at the bottom of the inverses section or should it go first?

Comment: @morgan Better to mention it is $\ne 0$ before dividing by it. If you already know that $\,\sqrt{2}\,$ is irrational (or, equivalently, $\,x^2 - 2\,\,$ is irreducible over $\,\Bbb Q)$ then you can use that.

Comment: @BillDubuque ok I will just simply mention it then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

After realizing that $\;0=0+0\cdot\sqrt2\;,\;\;1=1+0\cdot\sqrt2\;$, we see **all** the axioms of a field that are inherited to subsets are fulfilled in $\;A\;$ since the operations used are exactly the same as the ones in $\;\Bbb R\;$ .

The only thing thus that is left to show is closedness of operations and existence of multiplicative inverse. For the first ones you already were commented enough, as as for the last one think of

$$a,b\in\Bbb Q\;,\;\;a\neq 0\;\;or\;\;b\neq 0\implies\frac1{a+b\sqrt2}=\frac1{a+b\sqrt2}\cdot\frac{a-b\sqrt2}{a-b\sqrt2}$$

and now do the maths in the rightmost expression and use the fact the rationals is a field.

Comment: wait so your first statement basically proves that other axioms of addition and multipication?

Comment: @MorganWeiss If you meant to ask whether my first statement shows that commutativity, associativity and distributivity are fulfilled in $\;A\;$ then yes: it does.

Comment: I am having a hard time seeing how that is so, perhaps I will just stare at it for a few hours

Comment: @MorganWeiss Just think, for example, in associativity: why if $\;a,b,c\in A\;$ , then $\;(ab)c=a(bc)\;$ ? Because you can see both these sides happening **within the field** $\;\Bbb R\;$ ! That's all, and similarly for the other already mentioned inherited properties (**not all of them**, of course)

Comment: Yea I am still very lost, how do I show closedness of operations?

Comment: Nevermind I understand now will post my edited solution in a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

Please can we use the fact that it is closed under addition, subtraction, multiplication and division to prove that it is a field.